How to Solve "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'"
I tried adding
mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }

to my gradle but still not resolving problem tried both gradle offline and online mode but still not resolving problem
My build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    // buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.matrimonywebsite.www"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
 //   buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //__________for dimens_____________
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

    //_____________for OTP_____________
    implementation 'com.github.GoodieBag:Pinview:v1.4'

    //implementation 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:x.y.z'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    // implementation 'com.lyft:scissors:1.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.github.rahimlis:badgedtablayout:v1.2'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
//    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation('com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.12')
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

    // old implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    //new implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'

    // retrofit, gson
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    implementation files('libs/Pushwoosh.jar')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.brucetoo.pickview:library:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:17.1.2'

    implementation 'in.payu:payu-checkout-pro:1.8.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Error coming

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.


Can you share the scan if possible?
